# How to resolve "could not find driver" when running phpunit on Symfony

Tags: unit-testing, pdo, phpunit, symfony

My symfony app runs just fine... using the PDO driver I believe (though I'm not sure how to verify).

I've seen a stackoverflow question where it ended up being that the guy was running Laravel and it was trying to use sqlite. I don't belive that to be the case here but I don't know how to check.

When I run phpunit, however, I get this response:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:41
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2506
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3570
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3603
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:65
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:95
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php:58
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php:50
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:230
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:79
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:41
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2506
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3570
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3603
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:65
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:95
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php:58
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php:50
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:230
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:79
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

Caused by
PDOException: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:145
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:47
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2577
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:74
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php:61
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:41
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2577
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:74
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php:61
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:41
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2577
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:74
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php:61
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

Caused by
PDOException: could not find driver

/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:41
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:51
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1826
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4028
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:4115
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2577
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:310
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:74
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallMap.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php:61
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:106
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:43
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:136
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:168
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:62
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:131
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:315
/var/www/sitename.com/public_html/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:13

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Very appreciative for ANY insight that anybody can provide!!! Thanks

**UPDATE: Here's the test code:**

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertContains('TEST TEXT', $crawler->filter('#homepage .jumbotron')->text());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: Here's my phpunit.xml.dist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**And here's my autoload.php**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

return $loader;
```

**And here's the vendor/autoload.php**

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit2554ac6f5d571f82debebd2d3d7133d2::getLoader();
```

Attaching screenshot of cli / phpinfo modules.
[image]

Comment: You probably should show the code in the file that contains `testIndex`.

Comment: Thanks @AlvinBunk. Good point. I've added the code for the unit test.

Comment: That code looks good. How are you running your tests? Can you show the exact phpunit commands that you run and from which path, update your post showing this please.

Comment: Thanks again for the response @AlvinBunk - your questions are giving me ideas of things to check.

I'm in the public_html folder and I ran phpunit tests/AppBundle/Controller/

I noticed a message this time that said "Configuration read from /var/www/sitename.com/public_html/phpunit.xml.dist" I've edited the original question to include that file. I'm going to look and see if I need to add database connection information to that configuration file.

Comment: Did you run from your Symfony root folder, which is /var/www/sitename.com/public_html the command `phpunit`? And that's all, just `phpunit`.

Comment: Hey @AlvinBunk, I tried just now to make sure. I get the same error: "Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver."

Comment: If you got that error, I also suspect you have problems with your Symfony application as well. Doctrine errors have nothing to do with phpunit.

Comment: That's what is so weird. I'm clicking around and navigating my symfony application without any problems... writing to the database, reading from it, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the logs say, it is trying to use the [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) driver to connect to the database. If the website works when running through Apache/mod_php or PHP-FPM, then your configuration is different between the version of PHP that runs the website, and the CLI sapi that you use to run PHPUnit. Compare the list of PHP modules shown in of `phpinfo()` and `php -m`, which will show the modules available to the command-line 'cli' Server API.

Comment: thanks for the reply @AlisterBulman. I think you're right! I saw PDO in that -m list and thought that's what I needed. Can you take a look at this? Do you know what I need to install in Ubuntu to get pdo_mysql to work? (attaching screenshot)

Comment: You've already got pdo_mysql installed, but only enabled in the webserver. You also need to enable in in the CLI. `phpenmod  -s cli pdo_mysql` may be enough. Check with `php -m | grep pdo_mysql`.

Comment: Woohoo! You nailed it @AlisterBulman. I have PHP5 installed but when I installed phpunit, PHP7 got installed as well... php7 did NOT have the module installed while PHP5 did. Updating symlinks to point to php5 now allows the unit tests to run!!! I'd like to get PHP7 working though but I get "WARNING: Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available" ... would you mind letting me know if you know a way to fix this? Is it as simple as finding a ini file under php/5/mods-available and moving it to php/7.1/mods-available?

Comment: NM, got it! Had to get a php7 repo included and install the php7.1-mysql package

Comment: @AlisterBulman - I am using Ubuntu and it doesn't recognize phpenmod.  Ubuntu has php5enmod command.  I executed 'php5enmod -s cli pdo_mysql'.   Got no response.  When I execute php -m, it still didn't have php_mysql.

Comment: @user2305673 - Hi there.  I am having a similar problem with phpunit except that i am not using any framework.  Currently, I am using PHP 7.0.10 Ubuntu 14.04, MySQL 5.5.49.  I am using Amazon's Cloud9.  I cannot get PDO_mysql to be installed on CLI.  I really appreciate it if you can list each step in order to install PDO_mysql.  Thanks.